# TypeError: expected a character buffer object When execute a translate function

Tags: python, unicode

It's for removing punctuation of a `str`.

```
tbl = dict.fromkeys(i for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode)
                      if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P'))
def remove_punctuation(text):
    return text.translate(tbl)

remove_punctuation(',')
```

But it shows the error message when i run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled2/is_include.py", line 22, in <module>
    remove_punctuation('')
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled2/is_include.py", line 20, in remove_punctuation
    return text.translate(tbl)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: What Python version are you using?  In Python 2.x, `','` is of type `str`, not `unicode`, and `str.translate()` has a different prototype than `unicode.translate()`.  What's the result of `remove_punctuation(u',')`?

Comment: OP is using `xrange` and `unichr`, so Python 2.

Answer (score -1):

`text.translate()` is expecting a string.  Make sure you convert `tbl` to a string first.

```
def remove_punctuation(text):
    return text.translate(str(tbl))
```

UPDATE:

Or, as [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach) mentioned in the comment reply, you can use a unicode-translate instead.

`remove_punctuation(u',')`